# How to move an uploaded file and upload the path into mySQL database? Using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to know how i can move my uploaded file into my database and move it to a folder on my pc.

Here is my HTML CODE:

```
<form method="post" name="update" action="updateform.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" />

<label>Id:</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php print ("$row[id]")?>" name="id" />

<label>Logo:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileToUpload"/>

<input id="submit" type="submit" name="Update Record" value="update" />
```

Here is my PHP code (it's not all of it but just the parts you need):
I already made a database connection and that's working for my other inputfields.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
 //database connected

$id = $_POST['id'];

if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$folder="uploads/";
move_uploaded_file($file,$folder);
$handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'r');}

$query= "UPDATE config SET showimage = '$handle' WHERE id='$id'"

if (mysql_query($query)){
   echo "updated";
   header('Refresh:1;url=admin.php');}
else{
   echo "fail";}

// Close connection
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

I know i'm not using PDO or MySQLi so don't say that i have to use this to prevent MySQL injections...I know that?

But can someone tell me why my file path won't save in my database and why my file doesn't want to move to my folder??

Comment: You should write the path to your DB, not the actual image. `fopen() binds a named resource, specified by filename, to a stream.` So don't write `$handle`. You also are open to SQL injections, you could at least use `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent it a bit (you should update to `mysqli` or `PDO` at some point though unless you are using a system that can't be updated).

Comment: i know i'm open to SQL injections but i told you in my question that i can't change it? But can you answer with a change of my code because i don't fully understand it?

Comment: Is `move_uploaded_file` working (I thought you needed the name on the end of the destination, I haven't worked with uploads in awhile though..)? If so in place of `$handle` in your query write the location and the filename. Then where you output the image put that in the `src` of an `img` element. Also knowing you are open to SQL injections and just leaving it is very bad practice. There are ways to minimize the injection in almost every instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the path to be saved in db you should use this -

```
    <?php
     //database connected

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $folder="/uc webserver formulier/root/uploads/";
    move_uploaded_file($file,$folder.$filename);
    $handle = $folder.$filename ;
    }

    $query= "UPDATE config SET showimage = '$handle' WHERE id='$id'";

    if (mysql_query($query)){
       echo "updated";
       header('Refresh:1;url=admin.php');}
    else{
       echo "fail";}

    // Close connection
    mysql_close($db);
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your responsive a will test it out and let you know if it works

Comment: i get an error: 
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\Users\Stage\Desktop\uc webserver formulier\root\updateform.php on line 43

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Users\Stage\AppData\Local\Temp\php14E1.tmp' to 'uploads/' in C:\Users\Stage\Desktop\uc webserver formulier\root\updateform.php on line 43
updated

Comment: you should be using forward slash(/) instead of backward(\) in path

Comment: you should  also give a file name in move_uploaded_file($file,$folder.$filename)

Comment: i changed it to forward slashes + i'm testing the code right now

Comment: awesome it worked. Thank you all for the help... :-)